# Axios call not running in Gatsby onPostBuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby

I'm trying to get some data from FB using a list of posts I build up earlier in the build process. When I have this code in `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
exports.onPostBuild = () => {
  console.info(`console.log => 1`);
  const postSlugs = require('./content/post-slugs.json');
  const siteConfig = require('./gatsby-config');
  const siteUrl = siteConfig.siteMetadata.siteUrl.replace(/\/$/, '');
  console.info(`console.log => 2`);
  axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/?id=${siteUrl}${postSlugs[0]}&access_token=xxxxxx&fields=engagement`)
      .then(res => {
        console.info(`console.log => 3`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.info(`console.log => 4`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.info(`console.log => 5`);
      });

  console.info(`console.log => 6`);
};
```

The output I get is:

```
success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 5.746s
success Building HTML renderer - 1.073s
success Building static HTML for pages - 0.532s - 79/79 148.37/s
info console.log => 1
info console.log => 2
info console.log => 6
success onPostBuild - 0.045s
```

Why are none of the promise callbacks getting called?

I've tried the raw node api as well as axios for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the function to finish, using `async`/`await` should work. Something like:

```
exports.onPostBuild = async () => {
  console.info(`console.log => 1`);
  const postSlugs = require('./content/post-slugs.json');
  const siteConfig = require('./gatsby-config');
  const siteUrl = siteConfig.siteMetadata.siteUrl.replace(/\/$/, '');
  console.info(`console.log => 2`);
  await axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/?id=${siteUrl}${postSlugs[0]}&access_token=xxxxxx&fields=engagement`)
      .then(res => {
        console.info(`console.log => 3`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.info(`console.log => 4`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.info(`console.log => 5`);
      });

  console.info(`console.log => 6`);
};
```

Now, you can even isolate the logic:

```
exports.onPostBuild = async () => {
  console.info(`console.log => 1`);
  const postSlugs = require('./content/post-slugs.json');
  const siteConfig = require('./gatsby-config');
  const siteUrl = siteConfig.siteMetadata.siteUrl.replace(/\/$/, '');
  console.info(`console.log => 2`);
  
 let data= await fetchData();

  console.info(`console.log => 6`);
};

async function fetchData(){
     await await axios.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/?id=${siteUrl}${postSlugs[0]}&access_token=xxxxxx&fields=engagement`)
          .then(res => {
            console.info(`console.log => 3`);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.info(`console.log => 4`);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.info(`console.log => 5`);
          });
}
```